# Why do so many languages restrict string literals to a single source line?

Tags: c, language-agnostic, language-design, strings

In, for example, the Bash scripting language, the following creates a string called `$VAR` which begins at the first `"` quote and continues until the next unescaped `"` quote.

```
$VAR="
    hello
world!

this string preserves all
    whitespace"
```

This makes it very easy to write multiline strings without concatentation or a million annoying `\n`s everywhere, and it makes the parser *very* easy to write (speaking from experience) because you can just gobble everything between unescaped quotes with a regex like `"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"` or so.

Bash is (hopefully!) not a mission-critical or systems-programming language, but it is a systems-scripting language intended for *nx boxes on which *everything* is text, so perhaps it's apt.

Recall that Bash is written in C, and so this string is (probably) stored as `\n\thello\nworld\n` etc, but the point is the source written by the programmer (and the above is *far more readable*).

Many (I daresay C-influenced) "proper" Languages Used For Real Purposes find some unknown problem with allowing strings to contain literal newlines, and thus require one or more of the following:

- escape sequences`\n` (which get compiled into `\r\n` on Windows)
- special syntax (`""" multiline string """` in Py, `` `multiline string` `` in Go, or `R" raw string literal "` in C++11, etc)
- special functions to write newlines (Forth's `CR`, for example, although Forth gets a pass because it knows squat about strings)

I do not understand why more languages don't allow strings to be "implicitly" multiline.

Pros:

- ease of use & practicality, clearer code, etc
- simpler, more straightforward and thus  more maintainable parser (at least, for hand-written ones)

Cons:

- may make some code less readable, if abused
- ?

Is there an explicit reason this is the case, or has it just been blindly(?) adopted from C like so many other things?  Moreover, if I'm writing a parser or designing a language, is there a compelling argument as to why I should restrict string literals to a single line?

Comment: Forget a closing quote, then see what happens in various languages. Where will the error message locate the problem? Try to indent a multiline string to match the indentation of your source code. Would the indent be visible inside the resulting string? Or does the long string break your indentation because each line must start in column 1? Also, in C multiple literals are not much of an issue because adjacent string literals are concatenated by the compiler: `"a" "b"` in the source code is compiled as `"ab"`, which makes it easy to have a large string that is distributed over multiple lines.

Comment: @amon 1. It will say, "Syntax Error: Found EOF before closing quote at <index of beginning quote>." 2. Yes, the indent is part of the string literal, obviously. 3. The string does not "break" indentation, it has its content and it's fine. 4. Yes, but it is still in my opinion messy to write multiline strings, I am not talking about adjacent string literals.

Comment: Did someone downvote this because they think I'm a flaming moron, or because it's a bad question? If it's the former, then please craft an answer, and if it's the latter, then please yell at me in the comments!

Comment: Every language feature has a cost.  Most language features that don't get implemented are omitted because the cost exceeds the benefit.  To put it another way, language designers omit features because they decide to do so.  Why?  You'd have to ask them.

Comment: @cat: The problem with the "solution" to #1 is that it doesn't scale. If you have an unterminated string starting on line 100, and the next string start on line 200, you'll get an error about invalid code inside the second string, or if it's somehow legal code, you'll be told that the string on line 200 was unterminated. Repeat for more strings beyond line 200. The errors get rather unpleasant, and don't obviously identify the original source of the problem.

Comment: @ShadowRanger you have a point; a better static analysis tool would not be hard to create for such a language, but thankfully I have no interest designing serious languages for Use In Real Things

Comment: @cat: Except in the case where the contents of the string are legal code, that same construct could easily be intended. Static analysis would be stuck with heuristics to determine whether one unterminated string literal is really unterminated, or actually the product of an indeterminate amount of perfectly legal code with a string preceding it. Ideally, compilers and static analyzers shouldn't have to resort to heuristics. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger "compilers and static analyzers shouldn't have to resort to heuristics" which is why Perl 6 doesn't have a static analyser yet :( But I'm imagining crafting this for a lang of my own design (considering I prefer functional, stack-based / point free style) and it doesn't seem all that impossible in practice

Comment: I don't understand how this is opinion based. I was asking for real, objective reasons why this is the case, and yes, the "should I implement this" is subjective but I argue it's the *objective sort of subjective*, as SE users like to say.

Comment: @cat your pros and cons bit in the question body suggest that you're looking for pros and cons - and that's opinion.  You also ask "Is there an explicit reason this is the case, or has it just been blindly(?) adopted from C like so many other things" which is asking the opinion of people because we cannot know the actual answer for it.  The question "Moreover, if I'm writing a parser or designing a language, is there a compelling argument as to why I should restrict string literals to a single line?" is again opinion on to what makes a compelling argument as all designs are trade offs.

Comment: Furthermore, your comments on various answers show that you are opinionated in what you are willing to accept: "I don't consider what the Wikipedia entry says are issues, to be issues".  This taken as a whole seems to indicate that you are looking for a discussion instead.

Comment: Most modern languages do support multiline strings, including c++, C#, Python, Go etc. But they all use a different quotation syntax than for single line strings. So maybe your question should really be why the languages use different quotes for single and multiline strings? The reason is twofold (1) by using a distinct quotation for multiline strings it is easier to detect the common syntax error which is to forget a closing quote on a single-line string (2) it makes it possible to have two string syntaxes, one using character escapes for special charactes and one not using escapes.

Comment: @JacquesB I'm aware of that; I noted that in the question. That is not my question. If that is your question, please [ask a new question](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @cat: The point is that it is useful to have two different syntaxes for string literals, one which uses escapes and one without ("raw"). For example raw strings (@"" in C#) are often used for regexes, since the regex language has its own escapes. The question of escaping linebreaks is just one part of this more general distinction. If you couldn't escape linebreaks in strings it would also be really annoying.

Comment: I was on the VB language design team when we decided to add multi-line strings in 2014. VB is one of the most IDE-friendly languages out there. I don't agree with other commenters on this topic about poor IDE experience - in fact it's great: (1) construct-matching means that you rarely get unmatched quotes; (2) if you nevertheless do get unmatched quotes, then large chunks get colorized like a string so you instantly see your mistake; (3) AST generation is plenty fast enough. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vbteam/2014/12/09/new-language-features-in-visual-basic-14/

Comment: I think that multiline strings don't have a obvious canonical semantics. Imagine if your code looks like this: "<tab>const x = 'hello<newline><tab><tab>world';".
Will this create a string with multiple tabs between "hello" and "world"? If so then there's no way to indent you code to look nice. If not then something mysterious and non-obvious is happening (which is a bad characteristic in a language!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW, [Ocaml](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html) accepts a limited form of multi-line string literal :

> String literals are delimited by " (double quote) characters. The two double quotes enclose a sequence of either characters different from " and \, or escape sequences from the table given above for character literals.
>
> To allow splitting long string literals across lines, the sequence \newline spaces-or-tabs (a backslash at the end of a line followed by any number of spaces and horizontal tabulations at the beginning of the next line) is ignored inside string literals.

and C++11 has [raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) so you can code:

```
const char* s1 = R"foo(
Hello
World
)foo";
```

Hence several languages have some ways to write multi-string literals.

Comment: That's interesting; I've never really used the ML languages because I think they have ugly, non-finger-friendly syntax but that's interesting. The C++11 thing is just parallel to the `""" python """` and `` `golang` `` special syntax

Comment: The C++11 thing is _not_ parallel to `""" ... """` in Python. The main feature of the raw strings in C++11 is that raw strings don't have any escapes in them (like `r"..."` in Python), not the fact that they're multiline. You couldn't tell this from the answer though...

Answer (score 16):

What happens when you *didn't* mean to have a multi-line string, but instead forgot to close the quote?

The parser will chew through the code until it hits another quote in a completely different part of the program, then proceed as normal. This will very likely lead to confusing, unrelated errors since the string is no longer the parse error. At worst, you get a program that compiles properly and does something completely different.

This is compounded by partial-processing of code in modern IDEs. As you're typing the string, you're going to cause this scenario naturally. That will cause the IDE to toss the cached AST since it sees a bunch of stuff has changed, leading to slower intellisense (and similar constructs).

Comment: If you forget to close the quote, that's your problem, and you either get a) "Syntax error: found EOF before closing quote at..." or b) another, unrelated quote being interpreted as the end of the string, except that will cause *that* string to orphan its closing quote and so in the end you get the same SyntaxError, rightly.

Comment: Modern IDEs are designed for Modern Languages. If Modern Languages used this, or if C had started out with this and thus influenced other languages to have it, then IDEs would be different, so that is a non-issue.

Comment: Moreover, Intellisense is for lazy people who don't Care To Type Things and probably deserve whatever hell breaks loose because Intellisense can't fix it for them.

Comment: Intellisense is for lazy people?  If you work on a codebase of reasonable complexity, it's an invaluable tool for remembering exactly what methods are defined on Foo.

Comment: @SamDufel perhaps, or perhaps you should go back and read the methods / documentation / docstrings on Foo so you know *exactly* what they do. I use autocompletion for names too, and it is indeed very handy (especially that the docstring and synopsis is there in the tooltip) but Intellisense manages to take autocompletion to the point of killing brain cells. Having said that, that is not the point of my question, but the fact IDEs are designed a certain way is because langauges are designed a certain way.

Comment: If I forget to close a quote, all the content that follows in my emacs buffer becomes *font-lock-string-face* ;-)

Comment: @cat Well now you *are* starting to seem like a flaming moron. Humans have better things to do than memorize the (sometimes exceedingly numerous) function declarations on any particular class or namespace or what-have-you. If you don't appreciate the benefits of a good IDE such as IntelliJ that eliminates the need to look up documentation in a lot of cases where you don't necessarily need to, then you are wasting valuable time that could be spent being more productive. This is especially true of functions built into SDKs. Sometimes I just want to quickly list all of the methods on `String`.

Comment: @cat I doubt that the most important thing when programming is to remember whether the "convert string to all uppercase" function is called `toUpper()` or `upper()` or possibly `toUpperCase()` (not a big deal if you're only literate in one language, horrible if you know and use a few more and they all can't decide on how to name common things).

Comment: @Voo yes, that is what autocompletion is for, but it needn't be so moronic as Intellisense

Comment: @cat "intellisense" is just a term for a larger group of features of which autocomplete is one. And to implement autocomplete you *have to* build an AST or some other abstraction of the kind, because well you actually *want* information about what types you have (and typing characters can obviously change what kind of type we have). Having to throw away some part of an AST of a single method is a non-issue though and exceedingly doubtful to have anything to do with why some languages still don't have the feature. After all quite a few with intellisense have multiline strings and do just fine.

Comment: @Voo I'm talking primarily about Visual Studio's Intellisense. I don't know why or how the rest of your comment is relevant, but fair enough.

Comment: I don't get the partial processing argument. Would the IDE need to throw away its AST when I type an opening brace that invalidates my program (or changes scope of everything or…) as well?

Comment: @cat So what did your "moronic" comment refer to if not the fact that VS (and every other autocomplete implementation) would have to throw out its AST in such a situation? You shouldn't throw words around in any case, but particularly not if you don't have enough background knowledge to actually judge the problem at hand.

Answer (score -2):

The preprocessor has already given meaning to newline characters.  You can't completely undo that at a higher level.  Compare:

```
char s1[] = "This is how macros work in C\nExample\n    #define IS_GOOD 1\n";
```

with

```
char s2[] = "This is how macros work in C
Example
    #define IS_GOOD 0
";
```

Clearly the second is easier to read (in a hypothetical C compiler that accepts multiline string literals).

It also doesn't do what you expected.  `s2` doesn't contain an example of C code at all, what you actually got was:

```
char s2[] = "This is how macros work in C\nExample\n";
```

oops.

Or, you can change the preprocessor grammar also, by making it aware of quoting.  Then you lose the ability to expand macros to definitions containing quotes.  Hardly any better.

Things that cause unexpected and confusing results are not desirable features.

Comment: The *C* preprocessor has given meaning to newlines. I am *not talking* about *forcing* the C standard to make strings work in this way; I am *not suggesting we should break or change existing languages*. That would not make any sense, because the C preprocessor is written for the C language which exists currently. I think you misread the question; never did I suggest implementing this. If C had this sort of string, then the preprocessor would not behave in that way.

Comment: @cat I also addressed the idea of having the different preprocessor design. Try reading the answer completely before commenting (and voting)

Comment: But you're still only talking about C. I'm not talking about *any specific language*.

Answer (score -3):

I cannot answer on the "why"; as far as I know language designers tend to copy the "bad stuff" as many times as the "good stuff" when designing a language based on other languages.

I do have to say that using RegEx to parse your code is not the best way to do it and writing a parser which can keep track of multiline strings might be harder than you would expect it to be especially if indentation is part of the language.

What I can say about designing a new string format is to not even use the double quote `"`. If I were to design a language I would use parentheses to encapsulate `"content"` and implement a function in the standard library like so:

```
let foo = String(This is my string which can be multiline and does not
                 need escape characters for anything other than \( and \).)
```

Comment: No, the regex is just a part of the parser, I am not *parsing* with regex. The regex exists to make handling string literals easier than without it.

Comment: How are `(` and `)` in your fictional language different from `"` in a normal language?

Comment: @Bergi Makes nesting a heck of a lot easier if done wisely. The example here really shouldn't need the backslash escapes. Only an unpaired `)` should need to be escaped.